# Why isn't my Angular child component updating

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-changedetection

Using Angular 14.2, I have a child component which receives an array from its parent and is supposed to show the updated array.

But it doesn't.

If I click to another page and come back to this one, the messages are displayed, so I know that they are being received by the child, just not displayed.
All of the examples I've looked at say this should work, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here is my code on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1dtcms?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts. This code has the error - I see all of the `console.log` entries when they are received in the subscription, including that the value is added to consoleMessages array (the length increases), but the values are not shown in the JobConsole component.

### RxJS Subject

There is an RxJS Subject elsewhere in my app which emits values.  To simulate this on StackBlitz, I have the following code in my `main.ts` file:

```
const int = interval(3000).subscribe((n) => {
  console.log('emitting from main: ', n);
  subj$.next(n);
});
```

### Parent Component

```
<job-console [msgs]="consoleMessages"></job-console>
```

```
subj$.subscribe(n => {
      console.log('received in AppComponent', n);
      this.consoleMessages = [n.toString(), ...this.consoleMessages];
      console.log('consoleMessages length: ', this.consoleMessages.length);
    });
```

### Child Component

```
<div class="console">
  Messages should show here, but dont.  ???
  <div *ngFor="let item of msgs">--{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'job-console',
  templateUrl: './job-console.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./job-console.component.scss']
})
export class JobConsoleComponent  {

  @Input() msgs: string[] = []
 
}
```

Comment: for a test have you tried just this.consoleMessages = msg..  also what function are you performing that logic in?  also what happened when you tried ChangeDetectorRef?   Finally, are you Tim The Enchanter from Anime Pulse?? :)

Comment: Upload this in stackblitz and i will edit it for you

Comment: See StackBlitz link in updated post above.  Thanks.

Comment: IMHO, I suspect the problem is because you imported directly subj$ into component when it should have been injected via services or @Input. And data can't be transfered in that way. How do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interval is running outside of ngZone because you have defined it outside of the Angular app. It works if you bring the interval into the component

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bagy9m?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The fix wasn't exactly what I needed, but it was close and got me to the right place for the fix.  In my specific case, the ultimate source of the message was the "main" process of an electron app, which was outside the scope of zone.js so pointing that out was quite helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Let me explain how child selector works. Angular loads html first, so below html is loaded before ts logic.

```
<job-console [msgs]="consoleMessages"></job-console>
```

while the above code is loaded, you might not have the right value initialized for consoleMessages variable. All you have to do is to initialize consoleMessages with empty array in the beginning and have a extra if check in html, example below

```
<job-console [msgs]="consoleMessages" *ngIf="consoleMessages.length > 0"></job-console>
```

Each time when you are updating the consoleMessages, initialized with empty array again.

```
if(msg && msg.length > 0){
   console.log('msg recd: ', msg); // <-- this gets logged to console
   let messages = [...this.consoleMessages]; // save this data in a local variable before resting
   this.consoleMessages = [];
   this.consoleMessages = [msg, ...messages];
}
```

This will remove and update the DOM and with that you will have right data in place. I hope this solves your problem and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: If I set this.consoleMessages to [] before this.consoleMessages = [msg, ...this.consoleMessages]; then it will only contain msg - the spread operator will be over an empty array.

Comment: you are correct, I am updating the code please check

Comment: Did you even run OP's StackBlitz?